# KafkaListener dont read messages from topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have  class with KafkaListener:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class DocumentListener {

    @KafkaListener(topics = "${spring.kafka.consumer.from-hotfolder-transferer.topic}")
    public void listen(@Payload TaskDto taskDto, @Header(KafkaConst.HEADER_KEY) String serviceName) {
       ... some logic
    }
```

when the message hits the topic i see this in logs:

```
>! 2023-11-08T15:30:05.783+03:00  INFO [worker-ocr ] 28396 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : gpn-1: partitions assigned: [task-to-ocr-0]
>! 2023-11-08T15:39:03.175+03:00  INFO [worker-ocr ] 28396 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=gpn-1-0, groupId=gpn-1] Node -1 disconnected.
>! 2023-11-08T15:58:27.194+03:00  INFO [worker-ocr ] 28396 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig    : AdminClientConfig values: 
>! ______
>! here some values kafka admin
>! ______
>! 2023-11-08T15:58:27.219+03:00  INFO [worker-ocr ] 28396 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version: 3.4.1
>! 2023-11-08T15:58:27.219+03:00  INFO [worker-ocr ] 28396 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId: 8a516edc2755df89
>! 2023-11-08T15:58:27.219+03:00  INFO [worker-ocr ] 28396 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka startTimeMs: 1699448307219
>! 2023-11-08T15:58:27.235+03:00  INFO [worker-ocr ] 28396 --- [| adminclient-1] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : App info kafka.admin.client for adminclient-1 unregistered
>! 2023-11-08T15:58:27.242+03:00  INFO [worker-ocr ] 28396 --- [| adminclient-1] o.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics    : Metrics scheduler closed
>! 2023-11-08T15:58:27.243+03:00  INFO [worker-ocr ] 28396 --- [| adminclient-1] o.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics    : Closing reporter org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter
>! 2023-11-08T15:58:27.243+03:00  INFO [worker-ocr ] 28396 --- [| adminclient-1] o.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics    : Metrics reporters closed
```

My consumer property:

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class KafkaConfig {

    private final KafkaProducerProperties kafkaProducerProperties;

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, TaskDto> taskDtoConsumerFactory(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties, KafkaCustomProperties kafkaCustomProperties) {
        KafkaCustomProperties.KafkaConsumerProperties consumer = kafkaCustomProperties.getConsumer().get(KafkaConst.CONSUMER_CONFIG);
        Map<String, Object> prop = kafkaProperties.buildConsumerProperties();
        prop.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        prop.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, TaskDtoDeserializer.class);
        prop.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, consumer.getClientId());
        prop.put(ConsumerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, consumer.getClientId());
        prop.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, consumer.getPollInterval());
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(
                prop,
                new StringDeserializer(),
                new ErrorHandlingDeserializer<>(new TaskDtoDeserializer())
        );
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, TaskDto> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
            ConsumerFactory<String, TaskDto> taskDtoConsumerFactory,
            KafkaCustomProperties kafkaCustomProperties) {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, TaskDto> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(taskDtoConsumerFactory);
        factory.setCommonErrorHandler(errorHandler(kafkaCustomProperties));
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.RECORD);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setObservationEnabled(true);
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factory;
    }
```

With the settings of Kafka itself everything is ok, I can read messages from this topic using big data tools. Mapprop  i checked values is ok
What is wrong in my config?

Answer (score 0):

You've not set auto.offset.reset, so it'll default to consume from the end of the topic. If there's no producer running, you'll get no data

Also, this `from-hotfolder-transferer.topic` property isn't valid for [Spring Boot auto configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/messaging.html#messaging.kafka) . You can put your topic property anywhere else

Comment: Сonsumer connects to the topic, this can be seen in 1 message in the logs.
I tryed to set auto.offset.reset to earlest or latest its doesnt matter.

Comment: Yes. It does connect. I answered there's no active producer to send data into the topic. Consumer won't do anything for an empty topic. Otherwise, you'll need to debug further with `kafka-consumer-groups` command

Comment: I push messages in topic with big data tools util, and i see this messages in topic

Comment: Okay, I'm not familiar with this tool. Kafka has builtin cli tools to help you debug the issue, including the one I mentioned... If you're using the same group id in your UI as Spring app, then you'll also get no events there since they've already been consumed (which you'd see by describing the consumer group)

Comment: no, ui have different group id  than the spring app

Comment: Please edit your question to include kafka-consumer-group command output describing your group